# Microsoft.ML.OnnxConverter fails to export NormalizeMeanVariance estimator with useCdf = true

Tags: c#, .net, ml.net

I am using ML.NET for a multiclassification task. I am exporting the trained model to ONNX using `Microsoft.ML.OnnxConverter`.

My training pipeline is as follows:

```c#
            var trainerOpts = new LightGbmMulticlassTrainer.Options {
                UseZeroAsMissingValue = false,
                LabelColumnName = @"Label",
                FeatureColumnName = @"Features",
                LearningRate = 0.08,
                NumberOfIterations = 1000,
                NumberOfLeaves = 50,
                MinimumExampleCountPerLeaf = 5,
                Booster = new DartBooster.Options {
                    TreeDropFraction = 0.04,
                    FeatureFraction = 0.80,
                    MaximumTreeDepth = 8
                }
            };
            var pipeline = mlContext.Transforms.Conversion.MapValueToKey(
                outputColumnName:@"Label",
                inputColumnName:@"Label",
                addKeyValueAnnotationsAsText:false
            )
            .Append(
                mlContext.Transforms.NormalizeMinMax(
                    outputColumnName: "Features", 
                    inputColumnName: "Features",
                    fixZero: true/*,
                    useCdf: true*/
                )
            )
            /*.AppendCacheCheckpoint(
                mlContext
            )*/
            .Append(
                mlContext.MulticlassClassification.Trainers.LightGbm(
                    trainerOpts
                )
            )      
            .Append(
                mlContext.Transforms.Conversion.MapKeyToValue(
                    outputColumnName:@"PredictedLabel",
                    inputColumnName:@"PredictedLabel"
                )
            );
```

If I use `NormalizeMinMax` I am able to export the ONNX model successfully. However, If I use `NormalizeMeanVariance` with `useCdf: true`, the ONNX export fails:

```c#
                ...
                mlContext.Transforms.NormalizeMeanVariance(
                    outputColumnName: "Features", 
                    inputColumnName: "Features",
                    fixZero: true,
                    useCdf: true
                )
                ...
```

```c#
Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: The targeted pipeline can not be fully converted into a well-defined ONNX model. Please check if all steps in that pipeline are convertible to ONNX and all necessary variables are not dropped (via command line arguments).
   at Microsoft.ML.Runtime.Contracts.Check(IExceptionContext ctx, Boolean f, String msg)
   at Microsoft.ML.Model.OnnxConverter.SaveOnnxCommand.ConvertTransformListToOnnxModel(OnnxContextImpl ctx, IChannel ch, IDataView inputData, IDataView outputData, LinkedList`1 transforms, HashSet`1 inputColumnNamesToDrop, HashSet`1 outputColumnNamesToDrop)
   at Microsoft.ML.OnnxExportExtensions.ConvertToOnnxProtobufCore(IHostEnvironment env, OnnxContextImpl ctx, ITransformer transform, IDataView inputData, String[] outputColumnNamesToKeep)
   at Microsoft.ML.OnnxExportExtensions.ConvertToOnnxProtobuf(ModelOperationsCatalog catalog, ITransformer transform, IDataView inputData, String[] outputColumns)
   at Microsoft.ML.OnnxExportExtensions.ConvertToOnnx(ModelOperationsCatalog catalog, ITransformer transform, IDataView inputData, Stream stream)
... (omitted)
```

It looks like a limitation in the `Microsoft.ML.OnnxConverter` capability (in the current ver 0.20.1). Has anyone found a solution or workaround for this?